# Fluid sim animation timing; must wait for many frames for 'water' to fill stream

Tags: fluid-simulation

Working with a fluid sim of water flowing in a stream.  All is working well except I have to wait for about 200 frames before the water makes it all the way to the end and reaches a stable point where I have the right amount of water throughout the scene.  Clearly this is wasted time wrt baking, rendering and animating.  Is there some easy way to instruct the water sim to 'get to the point' w/o screwing up the volume or speed of the liquid
[image: 130 Frames]
[image: 200 frames]

Comment: In the domain settings, you can increase the Time Scale value? It's going to speed up the water

Comment: As @moonboots said, you can change the _Time Scale_ value - yes, you do not want to change the speed of the liquid, but you can animate the value with keyframes. A higher value at first to quickly fill up the river bed and then decrease the value to 1 for the normal flow. It might help to set the _Time Step Minimum_ to 2 for accuracy (but increases baking time as well). Or increase _Sampling Substeps_ on the flow object. This way not so many frames are wasted. Or Chris' answer is what I also would have suggested, simply place a body of water there initially so that the inflow only adds to it.

Answer (score 4):

just add another object with flow liquid geometry, what should be filled directly. Add an inflow additionally.

[image]

[image]